# Swift Event decoder failed: varint overflow

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I am using Core Data to save user information. Sometimes i get this error "Event decoder failed: varint overflow " What does it mean and how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Does removing and installing again the app solve this?

Comment: Anything on this?

Comment: Coredata uses SQLite which uses varint extensively. Maybe look in that direction? Otherwise your question doesn’t have much to go on.